Child-to-Parent [Object Object] value
I have this query
Opportunity__c oppPricebook = [SELECT ID, Pricebook__c
                                FROM Opportunity__c 
                                WHERE ID = :oppID];
 

Id pricebookId = oppPricebook.Pricebook__c;

Opportunity__c opp = [SELECT ID, 

(SELECT ID, List_Price__c, Quantity__c, Sales_Price__c, Total_Price__c, 
                              Pricebook_Entry__r.ID, 
                              Pricebook_Entry__r.List_Price__c.Name,
                              Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__c, 
                              Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r.Product_Code__c, 
                              Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r.ID
                       FROM Opportunity_Products__r
                       WHERE Pricebook_Entry__r.Pricebook__c = :pricebookId)
                      FROM Opportunity__c 
                      WHERE ID = :oppID];

Model Relation
Pricebook is the parent of opportunity and pricebook entry
Opportunity is the parent of opportunity product
product is the parent of  opportunity product and pricebook entry
Problem:
In inner query I am getting the values of everything correctly, but those two values
Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r.Product_Code__c,
Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r.ID
I am getting a Column called Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r with values [Object Object]
What could be the reason. Thanks

using custom opportunity, opportunityLineItem, etc instead of OOTB is something I'd avoid at all costs - you really limit your SFDC license and shut yourself out of a whole range of appExchange products

The issue you're encountering is due to how Salesforce handles relationship queries. When you're querying for fields on related objects, Salesforce returns an SObject for the related object, not a simple value. This is why you're seeing [Object Object] in your results - it's the string representation of an SObject.
In your case, Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r is an SObject representing the related Product__c record. To access the fields on this record, you need to cast the SObject to the appropriate type (Product__c in this case) and then access the fields on it.
Here's how you can do this:
for (Opportunity__c opp : [SELECT ID,
    (SELECT ID, List_Price__c, Quantity__c, Sales_Price__c, Total_Price__c, 
    Pricebook_Entry__r.ID, Pricebook_Entry__r.List_Price__c.Name, 
    Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__c, Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r.Product_Code__c, 
    Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r.ID 
    FROM Opportunity_Products__r 
    WHERE Pricebook_Entry__r.Pricebook__c = :pricebookId) 
    FROM Opportunity__c WHERE ID = :oppID]) {
    
    for (Opportunity_Product__c oppProd : opp.Opportunity_Products__r) {
        Product__c product = (Product__c)oppProd.Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r;
        System.debug('Product Code: ' + product.Product_Code__c);
        System.debug('Product ID: ' + product.Id);
    }
}

In this code, I'm iterating over the Opportunity_Product__c records related to each Opportunity__c, casting the Product__r field to Product__c, and then accessing the Product_Code__c and Id fields on it.

The loop stop when accessing this row
Product__c product = (Product__c)oppProd.Pricebook_Entry__r.Product__r;
I tried to print something on screen after this line and nothing shows, It's like it throws an exception or something else

N.B. the casting is unnecessary
